# How to restrict what content types can be added to a Book?

Tags: nodes

In activating the book module, I've noticed that all other content types on a Drupal 7 site have an option to add their nodes to a book. It would be ideal to restrict only the book nodes to go into a book. Does anyone know how to prevent other content types from being allowed to join the book party?

Comment: You can use `hook_form_alter` to alter the form and remove other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be within the permissions. For books there are a few main permissions (plus others in the Node section):

- Administer book outlines
- Create new books
- Add content and child pages to books

*Removing* the '**Administer book outlines**' will allow roles who have the other two permissions to create book pages but not see the option to add other content type nodes into a book. This is exactly what I was looking for.